# Issue connecting to my postgres database instance

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to my postgres database via Docker. I have confirmed that it is running (port 5432) along with my database manager tool called Adminer (port 8080). So far so good!

Next, I attempt to make my database migrations. (Here's the [Makefile](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/blob/main/Makefile)) by running the following command:

*FYI, [migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) is a database migration tool for Golang*

```
migrate -source file://migrations -database postgres://postgres:secret@localhost:5432/syndicate?sslmode=disable up
```

My database URL checks out:
`dbdriver://username:password@host:port/dbname?param1=true&param2=false`

But receive this error:

`error: pq: role "postgres" does not exist`

Here's what I know:

- Database name is `syndicate` ([database.env](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/blob/main/database.env))
- Default database user is `postgres` ([database.env](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/blob/main/database.env))
- Password is `secret` ([database.env](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/blob/main/database.env))

Why would the default postgres user require a role?

I created this [issue](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/issues/1) and have been narrating it as I receive feedback from various platforms. Here's my full [repo](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate)

One last thing...

The only thing i could find that was similar to my issue is this documentation, [PostgreSQL 1.3. Creating a Database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/tutorial-createdb.html) stating:

> Another response could be this:

`createdb: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "joe" does not exist`

> where your own login name is mentioned. This will happen if the administrator has not created a PostgreSQL user account for you. (PostgreSQL user accounts are distinct from operating system user accounts.) If you are the administrator, see Chapter 18 for help creating accounts. You will need to become the operating system user under which PostgreSQL was installed (usually postgres) to create the first user account

That is all, thank you!

Edit:
As suggested, I added a POSTGRES_USER to [database.env](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/blob/main/database.env):

```
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
POSTGRES_DB=syndicate
POSTGRES_USER=user
```

database.env is referred to in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/connorjcantrell/syndicate/blob/main/docker-compose.yml):

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
  db:
    image: "postgres"
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

Now receiving error:
`error: pq: role "user" does not exist`

Comment: "go" and "golang-migrate" are irrelevant tags.

Comment: I removed the tags, thanks

Comment: Can you connect with psql? Try `psql -h localhost -U user -d syndicate`

Comment: Received the same error, its as if the database doesn't exist. I can confirm that I have a local image running

Comment: Please paste the output of the following: a) `docker-compose ps` b) `docker ps` c) `ps -ef | grep postgres` d) `docker inspect <container id>`

Comment: $ docker-compose ps
`syndicate_adminer_1   entrypoint.sh docker-php-e ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`
`syndicate_db_1        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up      0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp`

Comment: Sorry for the poor text formatting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227238/discussion-between-connor-cantrell-and-jonathan-jacobson).

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL, a user is a type of role. If role "postgres" does not exist then it means that you don't have a "postgres" user in the DB.

Look into the Docker container settings. The official builds require you to provide the name of the default user. Check what user the gave it as the default.

Comment: "This optional environment variable is used in conjunction with POSTGRES_PASSWORD to set a user and its password. This variable will create the specified user with superuser power and a database with the same name. If it is not specified, then the default user of postgres will be used." - https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: Am I looking at the correct documentation?

Comment: @ConnorCantrell yes that's it

Comment: Yeah, I tried defining a user. I continued to have the same error

Comment: @ConnorCantrell what user did you define? Please attach the docker-compose.yml contents in your question.

Comment: Just added docker-compose.yml contents. I'm getting the same error, but with the newly defined user named "user"